# Radical of projection equals projection of radical?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Given an Lie Algebra $L$ (of finite dimension and over an algebraically closed field with zero characteristic) and an ideal $I$, is it truth that

$rad\left(\dfrac{L}{I}\right)= \pi(rad(L))$,

where $\pi$ is the projection? 
What happens if $L$ isn't finite dimensional? 
And if the field has positive characteristic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter-example for the infinite dimensional case:

Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $\{e_i\mid i\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ and $V_p=\langle e_i\mid i=1,\dots,p\rangle$. Consider
$$\mathfrak{t}_\infty:= \{ x \in \mathfrak{gl}(V)\mid x(V_i)\subset V_i \} .$$
as a lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$.

Let $E_{ij}$ be the linear transformations on $V$ such that $E_{ij}(e_j)=e_i$ and $E_{ij}(e_p)=0$ if $p\neq j$. Then, we have the formula
$$[E_{ij},E_{kl}]=\delta_j^kE_{il}-\delta_l^iE_{kj}.$$

Convince yourself that
$$\mathfrak{h}:=\{x \in t_\infty \mid x(V) \subset \langle e_i\mid i>1\rangle \}$$
is an ideal of $\mathfrak{t}_\infty$.

So, we have that
$$rad( \mathfrak{t}_\infty / \mathfrak{h})=$$

$$\langle E_{1j} \mid j>1\rangle / \mathfrak{h}.$$

Suppose, by absurd, that
$$\pi ( rad(\mathfrak{t}_\infty) ) = $$

$$rad( \mathfrak{t}_\infty / \mathfrak{h}) =$$

$$\langle E_{1j}\mid j>1\rangle / \mathfrak{h}.$$
This implies that
$$\langle E_{1j}\mid j>1\rangle + \mathfrak{h} = $$

$$rad(\mathfrak{t}_\infty) + \mathfrak{h}.$$

Therefore,
$$\langle E_{1j}\mid j>1\rangle + \mathfrak{h} \ni E_{12}=$$

$$x + y \in rad(\mathfrak{t}_\infty) + \mathfrak{h}$$

for some $x \in rad(\mathfrak{t}_\infty)$ and $y \in \mathfrak{h}$. Then

$$rad(\mathfrak{t}_\infty) \ni $$

$$[E_{11},x]=$$

$$[E_{11},E_{12}]-[E_{11},y]=$$

$$E_{12}+0=E_{12}.$$

This, again by the formula given above, implies that

$$rad(\mathfrak{t}_\infty)$$

contains

$$t_\infty ':=\{x \in \mathfrak{t}_\infty\mid x(V_1)=0\textrm{ and } x(V_i)\subset V_{i-1}, i>1\}$$
that is a non-solvable ideal of $\mathfrak{t}_\infty$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about infinite dimensions and/or positive characteristic, but the answer is **Yes** in the finite-dimensional, zero characteristic case.

In your situation we have an exact sequence of Lie algebras
$$
  0 \longrightarrow I \longrightarrow L \stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} L/I \longrightarrow 0
$$
Let $r_L < L$ be the radical of $L$.  Then $\pi(r_L)$ is a solvable ideal of $R/I$ and hence it is contained in its radical $r_{L/I}$, so that
$$
 \pi(r_L) < r_{L/I}
$$

My original answer had an error, which Kevin Ventullo pointed out in a comment below.  He also kindly fixed it in his second comment, which I include here for completeness, but the credit is due solely to him.

The Levi factor of $L$, which is semisimple and isomorphic to $L/r_L$, surjects onto $(L/I)/\pi(r_L)$, whence $(L/I)/\pi(r_L)$ has to be semisimple as well, whence we get the other inclusion
$$
  r_{L/I} < \pi(r_L)
$$

Comment: I'm confused. $\pi^{-1}(r_{L/I})$ contains $I$, so it need not be solvable.

Comment: Here's a fix for the second half: if $\pi(r_L)$ was not all of $r_{L/I}$, we could quotient $L$ and $L/I$  by $r_L$ and $\pi(r_L)$ respectively, and get a surjective map from a semisimple Lie algebra to a non-semisimple Lie algebra, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Yes, I made an error in the second part (although not sure exactly where!) and your second comment fixes it.  I will edit the question accordingly.
